# Compile standalone exe problems

Tags: qt, qt-creator

So I made a program using Qt Creator (Windows) and I compiled and ran it.  It runs fine on my computer, but when I send it to a buddy of mine, he gets these errors:

`The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

`The program can't start because mingwm10.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

What can I do for the exe to basically be standalone, so I can just send the exe anywhere and be able to run it without error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess static linking is what you want, see [these Qt docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/deployment-windows.html) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Alright, I did that, but when running `mingw32-make sub-src`, I get the following error.

http://chiggins.pastebin.com/h0hQXYTN

Comment: Here it is stated that it is a bug:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31684-Problems-creating-Qt-4.6.3-static-with-MinGw, so you could try 4.7 version with -no-qt3support.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you used gcc in mingw to compile the program. You can either distribute those two dlls with your program (they're found in C:\Qt\YOUR_VERSION\mingw\bin) or do a static build as 7vies suggested.

Answer (score 1):

He does not need to install Qt on his computer. You need to link the Qt libraries and build them into your executable, or include the necessary dll/library files with the distribution. You have to statically link to the Qt libraries/files/etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

He needs to install the Qt library on his computer. Tell him to go [here](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows/).